# R: Picking cumulative sum median value

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I am relatively new R user and now I have a problem with cumulative sum values.

I have a data frame with my original values and their cumulative sum values. I have also calculated the total sum of values and divided it by 2. --> 14511.087 (median value).

Is it possible to read cumulative sum column and choose the first value that is over 14511.087 (in this case value 7) and save this g_pred value (702.552604) in a vector?

|  | g_pred | cum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.296899 | 5.296899 |
| 2 | 6.249253 | 11.546153 |
|  |  | ... |
| 6 | 668.3405 | 1371.6481 |
| 7 | 702.5526 | 2074.2007 |
|  |  | ... |
| 34 | 1245.881 | 29022.173 |

Can I use vectors instead of data frames? Already have multiple for-loops, so is it possible to do this without a loop?

Comment: About the vector thing. If you have the "g_pred" values in a vector you can get another vector with its cumulative sums with the `cumsum` function. Not sure if this answers your question or not.

Answer (score 1):

In `base` R you could do

```
first_over_median <- df$g_pred[df$cum>median(df$cum)][1]
```

to keep the first "g_pred" value over the median of "cum".

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me even I noticed that for some reason my data frame numbers were incorrect.